# get third party library versions in Java

Tags: java

In Python, after importing libraries, you can easily get their version numbers. For example for `json`, you can easily get its version by using `json.__version__`. Is there a way in Java that can do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If the third party library has properly configured its manifest,* you can use [Package.isCompatibleWith(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#isCompatibleWith-java.lang.String-) (preferred) or [Package.getSpecificationVersion()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getSpecificationVersion--) (less desirable).  The latter is less desirable since you'd have to do the numeric matching yourself.

For instance:

```
Class<?> thirdPartyClass = org.apache.log4j.Logger.class;
if (thirdPartyClass.getPackage().isCompatibleWith("2.0")) {
    // Do stuff specific to Log4j 2
}
```

**However,** a lot of third party products don't bother setting the `Specification-Version` line in their jar's manifest, or worse, they set it incorrectly.  (JBoss has been a big offender in this regard historically, even going so far as to replace other third parties' specification versions with invalid ones.)  The contract of the manifest is that a specification version must contain only digits and non-consecutive periods, and must start and end with a digit, so straightforward numeric comparisons can be performed.

Answer (score 5):

There is a standard, but it's not commonly used. You may well be able to pull version info [out of the jar's MANIFEST.MF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file, but that will be particular to a library/vendor etc. Hopefully if you're only interested in a few particular libraries, then you can accommodate whatever notation they've adopted.

Comment: :( what a bad surprise. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking further... How do you get all third party jars that the project uses without hard cording it?

Comment: It is planned to be added in java 9 in approx. 2016

Comment: No way to get all dhird party jars. You need to use gradle or maven for that

Comment: There most certainly is a standard.  See my answer below.

Comment: @VGR - Thanks for that. I've now amended to reflect the fact that a standard exists, even if it's not standard practise

Comment: For your question  Gnijuohz, there is a tool from Jboss Tattletale. Its a 1.5MB standalone program which gives the dependencies, unused jars etc. and its FREE